# Unable to setup Node in mac for hub in windows

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, safaridriver

While setting up Selenium Grid:
Windows as Hub 
Mac as Node

While registering node in mac, the below error is displayed:
**Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: The hub responded with 305: Use Proxy**

**Note:**

(1) Able to setup Selenium Grid successfully, By

-> Windows as Hub and Node

-> Mac as Hub and Node.

-> Mac as Hub and Windows as Node

(2) Able to connect RDP from Windows to Mac

Comment: may be firewall is blocking the selenium grid port. please allowing tcp/udp packets in the firewall. the default port is 4444 for hub and 5555 for node.

Comment: Same port number has been used  for connecting hub and node. Also tried with different port numbers as well. (Hub->4444, 4445 and Node->5555, 5556)

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Could please help us to identify and resolve the issue ?